# How to change _NET_WM_NAME (X Library)

Tags: xorg, x11

I try use
http://xkbind.sourceforge.net/ (useful for displaying keyboard state in window title)
on my Mint Maya (based on Ubuntu 12.04)

But xkbind change only WM_NAME property

Here is xkbind.c code fragment

```
if(XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, window, &wa)) {
    XSelectInput(dpy, window, wa.your_event_mask&~PropertyChangeMask);
    XSync(dpy, False);
    XSetWMName(dpy, window, p_tp);
    XSelectInput(dpy, window, wa.your_event_mask);
}
```

What function should be used change _NET_WM_NAME property too?

Example

```
xkbind
gvim
```

xprop output

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Lat::[No Name] - GVIM"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "[No Name] - GVIM"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straightforward call of [XChangeProperty()](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XChangeProperty.html) should do the trick:

```
    XChangeProperty( display, win,
        XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_NAME", False),
        XInternAtom(display, "UTF8_STRING", False),
        8, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) utf8_buffer,
        count);
```